# Python Module not Found from within Github Download

Tags: python, pip

I want to install and use a library called [Synthetic Interventions](https://github.com/deshen24/Synthetic-Interventions). I install it like:

```
pip3 install -e git+https://github.com/deshen24/Synthetic-Interventions#egg=SI --user
```

I then go to my source folder (in my case located at C:/Users/jgrea/src/), where you should now see a folder called *si*. I rename this directory to *SI*.

```
SI
│   SI.py    
│
└───src
│   │   cvxRegression.py
```

But then, when I run my code

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\jgrea\\src")
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from SI import SI
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jgrea\src\SI\SI.py", line 4, in <module>
    from src.cvxRegression import ConvexRegression
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.cvxRegression'
(0 lines skipped)
```

I don't understand why I see this. When I look in the *src* folder in *SI*, I see a file named cvxRegression, the exact library *SI* asks for. So, why would this happen if we see this file in the folder in question? Perhaps, it's because there's no setup.py or init file?

Comment: The path separators look like they could be a problem. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python Also of course you can try not renaming this folder because that may be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: Okay I'll try this and then post back if it works, or if it doesn't.

Comment: The path separators are fine, when I keep the file name the same, and I use all backslashes, I get the same error as described above. So if it isn't the separators or the file name, what might the next most likely issue be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using all backslashes". I was thinking more along the lines of using double backslashes, or forward slashes. In any case, another problem might be that you are missing a package called cvxRegression (a missing dependency problem)

Comment: The library `cvxRegression` is [found](https://github.com/deshen24/Synthetic-Interventions/tree/master/src) in the github repository, so the missing dependency shouldn't be the issue. @topsail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with the author, the issue here is poor packaging-- the code they wrote was mainly for them and not meant necessarily to be a fully loaded package for everyone to use. The solution, for whatever reason, in this case is to change your directory to the SI folder, in my case

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\jgrea\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\SI')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are importing this file from a different directory other than `SI`, and since the imports in the module are absolute rather than relative, and also the SI directory and src directory do not have an `__init__.py`, so they are not a module.

You can either change the scripts in order to perform relative imports, add the SI directory to your path or attempt running your script in the same directory as `src` and `SI.py`.

Comment: @JaredGreathouse You might be importing `from SI import SI` and using the it as a function/class `SI()`

Comment: The SI you're improting is the file SI.py, if you want to use a function named SI inside of it, you can do `SI.SI()`